# After Effects What does this Icon mean

Tags: after-effects

Thanks in Advance,

Can someone help with explaining what this Icon mean couldn't find any reference, 
cheers

[image: Icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a slip-edit (see Adobe's explanation [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/after-effects/using/selecting-arranging-layers.html#trim_extend_or_slip_edit_a_layer)).
If you have the Pan-Behind tool selected, when you see this icon over a clip, it means you can drag the clip left or right in time, and the start and end points of the clip will change, but the position and duration in your timeline will stay in the same place.  It's just like doing a [slip edit in Premiere](https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/premiere-pro-slip-slide-editing/).

Comment: Thank you so much appreciate the help cheers